# Teradata SQL assistant

Tags: sql, database, regex-group, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

How to perform below operation using teradata,

> **Input string-** *'data1 data2 (1) (Ab-123)'*
>
> **output required-** *Ab-123*

So basically I want data from last bracket.

Comment: Is the last bracket always the last character or might there be other chars, e.g. `'data1 data2 (1) (Ab-123)bla'`?

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. No, bracket only will be last. No char after bracket.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a regular expression:

```
select regexp_substr('data1 data2 (1) (Ab-123)',
                      '[(]([^)]*)[)]$'
                     )
```

Comment: I believe it's `regexp_substr` in Teradata; `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('data1 data2 (1) (Ab-123)',  '[(]([^)]*)[)]$');` Although that holds on to the parentheses, so maybe something like `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('data1 data2 (1) (Ab-123)',  '^.*[(]([^)]*)[)]$', '\1');`

Comment: @JNevill . . . What do you know!  Teradata has rebranded Presto's documentation:  https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/148t/functions/regexp.html.  Because the function varies across databases, I usually check before answering (yeah I sometimes do that).  It doesn't always work, apparently.

Comment: I've never been out to the presto documentation. It's much nicer than Teradata's knowledge base! You are about to crack 1 million! We need to pop some champagne!

Comment: @JNevill: The Presto docu might be nicer, but it's Presto syntax, not Teradata :-)

Comment: @JNevil Thanks. It works perfectly. Any reference doc or link to understand this?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Presto documentations not work always due to syntax.

Comment: @AnkushGondane . . . You're missing the point.  I searched for Teradata documentation, but Presto came up.

Comment: @AnkushGondane. https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/bSkgRmSt8P48II0SKyyH3Q is a good source. That's specifically around `regexp_subtr()` which is a super handy function. The ugly stuff `'^.*[(]([^)]*)[)]$'` is regex code which you can hit up any regex tutorial/learning site to understand.